# How do i use a shell script output as input for perl script (to delete files with permissions)?

Tags: perl, shell

I am running a shell script on the mailq to create a list of files to delete, but i cannot delete them with shell script due to permissions (when i use root permissions the script works but i cannot always give root password for root permissions to a user). i would like to send the output list of files to perl in order to delete them and that Perl program has root priveleges.

the shell script is:

```
    #!/usr/bin/ksh
    WORKFILE="/tmp/check.mq"
    MAILLIST="yagyavalkbhatt@yahoo.com"

    mailq|grep -B1 -i temporarily |grep -iv deferred |egrep -i                 'jan|feb|mar|apr|may|june|jul|aug|sept|oct|nov|dec' |awk -F" " '{print $1}' |awk '{print substr($0,10,14)}'|tee $WORKFILE |awk '{print "*" $1}'|tee mail.mq

    mailq|grep -B1 -i unknown |egrep -i 'jan|feb|mar|apr|may|june|jul|aug|sept|oct|nov|dec' |awk -F" " '{print $1}' |awk '{print substr($0,10,14)}'|tee $WORKFILE  |awk '{print "*" $1}'|tee mail.mq

    mailq|grep -B1 -i lookup |grep -iv deferred |egrep -i 'jan|feb|mar|apr|may|june|jul|aug|sept|oct|nov|dec' |awk -F" " '{print $1}' |awk '{print substr($0,10,14)}'|tee $WORKFILE |awk '{print "*" $1}'|tee mail.mq 

    cat mail.mq | while read file; do rm /var/spool/mqueue/$file;done
    find . -type f -name "mail.mq" |rm -rf mail.mq
```

which creates output like:

```
    *##### where ##### is a unique 5 numbers to identify files in the mailq.
```

i want to know how i can delete these files with root priveleges from any user.

Comment: It sounds to me like you have some serious architecture problems here if you can't delete files but have access to a Perl program that can. I'd work on solving that issue before adding more gum and spit to the hole.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Redirect STDERR to STDOUT and read it together.

**Example:**

```
@ls_output = `ls -l 2>&1`;
```

Comment: i didnt get what you mean. can you explain in more detail?

Comment: @YagyavalkBhatt - 1st part of your question or actually subject of your question says "*How do i use a shell script output as input for perl script*", so I answer that part. If you wanna execute some shell command or script from Perl (such as command `ls -l`), then you need to use the above code in Perl to get its output. As some part of output is STDOUT and other is STDERR, you need to redirect it to one by `2>&1`. So when you run the above code, then `@ls_output` will contain output of `ls -l` shell command and you can use it in your Perl script for further processing. Is that what you want?

Comment: thanks for the quick answers. 
will PERL have permission to delete a file from mailq or do i have to change my code to PERL since i want to make the script executable by the user with root priveleges, but i dont want to use sudo or setuid. is there any work around to these?

Comment: @YagyavalkBhatt - You can execute your external script from Perl, so you don't have to clone it to Perl. Since you will execute Perl script from user with root privileges, so the external script will be, so you should be fine then. If you need more help with admin/privileges issues, then you have to post a new question about that, as it is more for admin people, not for Perl programmers, so be sure then to tag your question with correct tags, so people with knowledge will read and answer it. Good luck.

Comment: i created a c script with setuid to call the bash script, compiled with gcc, and chown and chmod 4755 the binary. this works now but are there any possible security loopholes, like users viewing or modifying the binary? thanks alot for the help and quick responses.

Comment: sorry, i cant vote up (not enough reputation) but i did acceptance. thanks again for the help.

Answer (score 1):

One good way of handling this is to allow users to create lists like this and save the output to files that goes in a given directory. You can then have a cron job periodically (frequently or infrequently) go through the lists submitted by users, check the content to make sure it's legit (you only want to allow certain files in certain directories to be listed for deletion), delete the files, then delete the list.

Giving root permissions to users is not a good idea. There are usually better ways to get the job done.

Comment: can i convert this script to PERL and use setuid. will that solve my problem?

And one more thing user will still not be able to create a list of those files since they dont have access to mailq

Comment: If the users don't have access to mailq, and therefore don't know which files to delete, why do you want to make this where users get to delete the files? Who is going to initiate this process, root or users? Who knows which files need to be deleted?